# Entity framework DBcontext add child row

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity-framework-4.1, entity

As I understand, to add a child row, you can either do

parent.Children.Add(child);

or

child.Parents= parent

Then you can do myContext.SaveChanges();

Somehow the second solution doesn't do the insert work at all. Here's my code:

```
        CountMaster countMaster = (from b in pMDataContext.CountMasters
                                   where b.ReportDate == reportDate && b.Department == dept
                                   select b).SingleOrDefault();



        CountDetail countDetail = new CountDetail { CategoryId = 1, StatusId = 1 };

        //countMaster.CountDetails.Add(countDetail);

        countDetail.CountMaster = countMaster;

        pMDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding an entity to the collection navigation property or setting it to a reference navigation property of an already tracked entity then EF will add that entity to the context in the `EntityState.Added` state. This is due to the `ObjectStateManager` detecting changes made to the tracked entity.

If you are working the other way around, that is, starting with an untracked entity and setting/adding tracked entities to reference/collection properties, then the `ObjectStateManager` has no way of detecting changes you make to that untracked entity. Therefore you need to explicitly add the entity to the context before `SaveChanges()`.

```
countDetail.CountMaster = countMaster;
context.CountDetails.Add(countDetail);
pMDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi, @bmused, your solution does work. But in Julie Lerman's book she states that you don't have to attach the untracked entity to a tracked entity if you set the parent property of countDetail to a tracked parent. countDetail.CountMaster = countMaster;   Has there been a change since her book came out?

Comment: @Shredding, haven't read the book. This is just my understanding from using EF4/EF5. Change detection can only occur for entities being tracked by the `ObjectStateManager`. If the entity is not tracked then there is no way for the `ObjectStateManager` to know of any changes you have made. In your first instance the ObjectStateManager is alerted to a new entity being added to a tracked entity and responds by adding that new entity to the `ObjectStateManager`. In the second instance the `ObjectStateManager` has no way of knowing of changes because the entity is not being tracked.